# multimap with unique key

Tags: c++, stl

Using a `multimap` like below:

```
multimap<int, string> mm;
mm.insert(make_pair(1, "jack"));
mm.insert(make_pair(1, "jack"));
mm.insert(make_pair(1, "jack"));
mm.insert(make_pair(1, "joe"));
mm.insert(make_pair(2, "david"));
mm.insert(make_pair(2, "daniel"));
mm.insert(make_pair(3, "alex"));

for (multimap<int, string>::iterator itr = mm.begin(); itr != mm.end(); itr++)
{
    cout << "key: " << itr->first << ", value: " << itr->second << endl;
}
```

results:

```
key: 1, value: jack
key: 1, value: jack
key: 1, value: jack
key: 1, value: joe
key: 2, value: david
key: 2, value: daniel
key: 3, value: alex
```

As you can see for the key `1` there is two different values `joe` and `jack` and it's ok. But there is two duplicated `<1,"jack">` in the container.

How can I get rid of that duplicated items?  Is there any standard container for my requirement?  Or, How we can combine existing containers to achieve my goal(The efficiency is very very important)?

Comment: Check if the map contains the pair before inserting one, better yet use `std::set<std::pair<int, std::string> >`

Comment: Would a `map<int, set<string>>` do the job? Or how about a separate `set<int>` of keys you could use to check for uniqueness? You'd need to write your own iterators in either case, for the new structures to be a drop-in replacement. edit: @ahenderson's suggestion is much simpler ;-)

Comment: @olibre: as he wrote, that is no problem when there are keys with the same value.

Comment: if the order doesn't matter, use the hash version: `unordered_map<int, unorderd_set<string>>` for better performance, but probably more space.

Comment: @matthew3r: I wrote my comment when no comment was displayed. Not very easy to understand what @MasoudM. means. I guess he wants to avoid printing duplicates lines... As you said he does not care there are duplicates within his `multimap`... but I am not sure... Cheers (PS: I have removed my redundant comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In STL you can use `std::pair` to create a container whose keys (or values) are composites of more than one value, so you could turn your `multimap` into a `set`:

```
set<pair<int, string> >
```

The resulting container can only contain one entry for each combination of the two values.

Comment: +1 nice and simple ;-) However, how to keep track of the number of duplicates. I have unsuccessfully attempted to give an answer based on  `multimap<pair<int, string>, int> mm; mm[make_pair(1, "jack")]++;` then on `struct st{ int i; string s; /*operators*/ }; multiset<st>` and finally on `multimap<st,int>`... because I guess @MasoudM. wants to know the number of occurrences...